# Socket timeout but servers logs 200

Tags: java, php, amazon-elb

I have a Java client using `org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient` calling a PHP system sitting behind an AWS ELB. Approximately once or twice a day one of the requests fails with `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`.

The server receives the request and it logs a 200, it never takes more than 2 seconds, less than connection request timeout or socket timeout. However, neither ELB nor the Java register the response and after 30 minutes (the socket timeout) Java fails with a socket timeout.

Any clue of what can be happening?

Answer (score 0):

1. Basically on `SocketTimeout`, you client had a transfer time out setting and there was no bits flowing through the channel for that duration and exited with `SocketTimeoutException`.
2. Server is not aware of it and has completed the request successfully and hence it logs `200`
3. If there multiple proxies involved, there are chances of someone misbehaving or losing connection and causing the error to client
4. Better to add some trace header and check your different proxies and redirects.

Tracing requests without traces and consolidated logs will be little challenging.

Comment: Sorry, what would exactly be a trace header. Can that be configured at the apache library?

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim, Unfortunately tracing is never a first class citizen in whole network world. Every application should build a custom tracing solution. Basically this is what is have seen in blogs of top internet companies, 1. Decide on a common header parameter, 2. Generate a unique id per request as a value of this header. 3. Ensure a framework to manage this header across all components involved in the service (proxies, application servers, client module). 4. Tie the information generated across these services under a common aggregation service.